# Why after pressing "ok" button in numeric sofkeyboard the alphanumericsoftkeyboard appears?

Tags: android, android-layout

When i click on EditText numeric keyboard apperas, type some difgits and then pressing "ok" the normal keyboard appears which is binded to no Edittext. The numeric keyboard should just disappear. How to fixt it?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<TextView
    android:text="@string/short_instruction"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLength="4"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/number_vehicle_hint"
    android:id="@+id/somenumber"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

<Button
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:onClick="reportButtonPerform"
    android:text="@string/report_button"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/ad_banner"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    ads:adUnitId=";)"
    ads:adSize="BANNER" />
```

Comment: Could you show your EditText code in your Activity?

Comment: Do you have any other EditText/Picker in your Layout besides that one?

Comment: Some view is taking focus before your EditText, that is why the normal keyboard is being opened before the alphanumeric keyboard does

Comment: There is no other EditText in whole app, but it looks like cliking the ad banner opens normal keyboard, but why? No, additional code for this EditText, just ((EditText)findViewByID(R.id.somenumber)).getText().toString()